# How to I create links dynamically in Jekyll?

Tags: jekyll

I have a projects collection in my Jekyll project and I would like to link to each document item. I have a projects include where I would like to do this. At the moment I am able to iterate over each project and access the front matter attributes by doing something like:

```
{% for project in site.projects %}
  <h4>{{ project.title }}</h4>
  <p class="text-muted">{{ project.subtitle }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

I can link using an `<a>` tag at the moment with this:

`<a href="{{ site.baseurl }}{% link _projects/1.md %}">`

But I would like to do it dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the url of a page under a collection via its [`url`](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/collections/#output) attribute.

So in your case you should just adapt your code this way:

```
{% for project in site.projects %}
  <h4>{{ project.title }}</h4>
  <p class="text-muted">{{ project.subtitle }}</p>
  <a href="{{ project.url }}">See this project</a>
{% endfor %}
```

---

Given the structure:

```
.
└── _projects
    ├── project-a.md
    └── project-b.md
```

This would give you

- `/projects/project-a.html`
- `/projects/project-b.html`

If you don't like those and want to customise the URLs of a collection, you can, in the `permalink` attribute of your collection defined in `_config.yml`.
This behaviour has its own documentation page: https://jekyllrb.com/docs/permalinks/

Given this configuration in __config.yml_

```yaml
collections:
  projects:
    permalink: /:collection/:name
```

The exact same structure will now give me

- `/projects/project-a`
- `/projects/project-b`